# How to query a Mongo database with multiple keywords at once?

Tags: r, database, mongodb

I have hundreds of keywords, which I need to query in the Mongo database. So far I'm doing it like that:

```
{keyword: 'lampa stołowa'}
{keyword: 'lampa na stół'}
{keyword: 'lampa do pokoju'}
```

however doing it one by one takes ages (I'm doing it in Rstudio, but still it takes a long time).
Anybody knows how to do it for all the keywords at once? Hopefully it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found an answer:

```
{keyword: { $in:["lampa stołowa", "lampa nad stół", "lampa do pokoju"]} }
```